# how to open multiple files and check values of all

Tags: python

I have three files:

`file1.txt`:

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.6
1.1.1.11
```

`file2.txt`:

```
Protocol  Address   Age (min)  Addr            Type   Interface
Internet  1.1.1.1         5    6026.aa11.1111  A      Ethernet1/49
Internet  1.1.1.2         -    0006.f2d2.2d2f  A      Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.3         -    6026.aa33.3333  A      Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.4         0    Incomplete      A
Internet  1.1.1.5         0    Incomplete      A
Internet  1.1.1.6         64   fa16.6edb.6666  A      Vlan1
Internet  1.1.1.11        23   fa16.7e7d.7777  A      Vlan1
```

`file3.txt`:

```
Unicast Entries
 vlan     mac address     type        protocols               port
---------+---------------+--------+---------------------+-------------------------
 1        6026.aa11.1111   static  ip,ipx,assigned,other Switch
 1        0006.f2d2.2d2f   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Ethernet1/24
 1        6026.aa33.3333   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Ethernet1/12
 1        fa16.6edb.6666   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Ethernet1/8
 1        fa16.7e7d.7777   dynamic ip,ipx,assigned,other Ethernet1/10
```

I'm going to iterate over all these files to check if IP of `file1` is found in `file2`, then check the value of `4th` column of `file2` for that IP, then find that file `file3` and print the last column of that value.

Not sure how, but I'm going to do something like this:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
        with open('file3.txt', 'r') as file3:
            # if ip in file1 found in file2,
            # then store Add value of that ip in a variable
            # then find that value in file3,
            # if it's found, then store the last column of that 'mac address' into another variable
            # finally print(f'ip {ip} addr {addr} port {port}')
```

This is expected output:

```
ip 1.1.1.1 addr 6026.aa11.1111 port Switch
ip 1.1.1.2 addr 0006.f2d2.2d2f port Ethernet1/24
ip 1.1.1.3 addr 6026.aa33.3333 port Ethernet1/12
ip 1.1.1.6 addr fa16.6edb.6666 port Ethernet1/8
ip 1.1.1.11 addr fa16.7e7d.7777 port Ethernet1/10
```

Comment: better off opening and parsing all the data you need from each file. then checking the data

Comment: @TheLazyScripter I'm afraid I didn't understand you completely. I'm guessing something but not sure if they're correct. I'll try my guesses and mention you again what I did.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

First load your data into dataframes, using e.g. [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) or [`read_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_clipboard.html).

I load the data here by manually typing it in:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ipv4":{"0":"1.1.1.1","1":"1.1.1.2","2":"1.1.1.3","3":"1.1.1.6","4":"1.1.1.11"}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  "Protocol":{ "0":"Internet", "1":"Internet", "2":"Internet", "3":"Internet", "4":"Internet", "5":"Internet", "6":"Internet" },
  "Address":{ "0":"1.1.1.1", "1":"1.1.1.2", "2":"1.1.1.3", "3":"1.1.1.4", "4":"1.1.1.5", "5":"1.1.1.6", "6":"1.1.1.11" },
  "Age (min)":{ "0":"5", "1":"-", "2":"-", "3":"0", "4":"0", "5":"64", "6":"23" },
  "Addr":{ "0":"6026.aa11.1111", "1":"0006.f2d2.2d2f", "2":"6026.aa33.3333", "3":"Incomplete", "4":"Incomplete", "5":"fa16.6edb.6666", "6":"fa16.7e7d.7777" },
  "Type":{ "0":"A", "1":"A", "2":"A", "3":"A", "4":"A", "5":"A", "6":"A" },
  "Interface":{ "0":"Ethernet1\/49", "1":"Vlan1", "2":"Vlan1", "3":None, "4":None, "5":"Vlan1", "6":"Vlan1" }
})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "vlan":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":1,"3":1,"4":1},
    "mac address":{"0":"6026.aa11.1111","1":"0006.f2d2.2d2f","2":"6026.aa33.3333","3":"fa16.6edb.6666","4":"fa16.7e7d.7777"},
    "type":{"0":"static","1":"dynamic","2":"dynamic","3":"dynamic","4":"dynamic"},
    "protocols":{"0":"ip,ipx,assigned,other","1":"ip,ipx,assigned,other","2":"ip,ipx,assigned,other","3":"ip,ipx,assigned,other","4":"ip,ipx,assigned,other"},
    "port":{"0":"Switch","1":" Ethernet1\\/24","2":" Ethernet1\\/12","3":" Ethernet1\\/8","4":" Ethernet1\\/10"}})
```

Then merge all three dataframes and only show the columns you're interested in

```py
maindf = df1.merge(df2, how="inner", left_on="ipv4", right_on="Address").merge(df3, left_on="Addr", right_on="mac address")
maindf[["ipv4", "Addr", "port"]]
```

|  | ipv4 | Addr | port |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.1.1.1 | 6026.aa11.1111 | Switch |
| 1 | 1.1.1.2 | 0006.f2d2.2d2f | Ethernet1/24 |
| 2 | 1.1.1.3 | 6026.aa33.3333 | Ethernet1/12 |
| 3 | 1.1.1.6 | fa16.6edb.6666 | Ethernet1/8 |
| 4 | 1.1.1.11 | fa16.7e7d.7777 | Ethernet1/10 |

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but the real file is not static and it's not easy to write them down:( How can I convert the files to what you mentioned in your answer? I mean `pd.DataFrame...`

Comment: "How to read a file into pandas" is a different question than you have now. For that it's best to ask a new question, but *please* do some research first and show in your question what you've tried.